# Postgres OR exclude operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a query on postgres but if one of the statement is true i don't want to apply the other where statement for example i have this query:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (pa.id) id,
pa.family_id,
pel.item_id,
pel.parent_id,
pel.group_id,
pel.coverage_type,
pel.start_date,
pel.end_date,
pel.updated_at,
pel.updated_by
FROM
patient pa
JOIN patient_eligibility_list pel ON pel.parent_id = pa.id
AND ((now()BETWEEN pel.start_dateAND pel.end_date)
OR (now() > pel.start_date)
OR (now() > pel.end_date))
WHERE
pel.group_id = 1575
AND pel.start_date < pel.end_date
ORDER BY
pel.end_date DESC;
```

On the **where** condition i need a operator that if the first statement is true does not validate the other statement

which one do you recommend?

Comment: Perhaps you want `OR`.

Comment: That's what the `OR` operator does.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "validate". All expressions will be parsed, and there is no guarantee which one will be checked first.

Comment: I want to execute in order if the first statement is true does not bring me the others records that match with the second and if the second is true  the query does not bring me the records that match with the third

Comment: You need an "exclusive or" operator, that **PostgreSQL** does not have... Might want to do it with `CASE .... END` expression...

Comment: Note: `... AND ((now()BETWEEN pel.start_dateAND pel.end_date)
OR (now() > pel.start_date)
OR (now() > pel.end_date))` Can (almost) be simplified  to `... AND(now() > pel.start_date)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the `OR` keyword wisely.
Your query should look something like this

```
select * from abc where a = True or (b= False and c = True)
```

Comment: you say that repeat the berfore statement to second like:

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean by `repeat the before statement to second like` ?

Comment: AND ((now()BETWEEN pel.start_date AND pel.end_date)
OR ((now()BETWEEN pel.start_date AND pel.end_date) = false AND now() > pel.start_date)
OR ((now()BETWEEN pel.start_date AND pel.end_date) = false AND (now() > pel.start_date) = false AND now() > pel.end_date))

Answer (score 0):

Seeing now that what you're wanting is Xor, which postgres does not have, so I've updated the code to provide the results you're looking for.

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT ON (pa.id) id,
 pa.family_id,
 pel.item_id,
 pel.parent_id,
 pel.group_id,
 pel.coverage_type,
 pel.start_date,
 pel.end_date,
 pel.updated_at,
 pel.updated_by
FROM
 patient pa
JOIN patient_eligibility_list pel ON pel.parent_id = pa.id
 AND ((now()BETWEEN pel.start_dateAND pel.end_date)
 OR (now() > pel.start_date)
 OR (now() > pel.end_date))
WHERE
 (pel.group_id = 1575 and pel.start_date >= pel.end_date)
or
 (pel.group_id != 1575 and pel.start_date < pel.end_date)
ORDER BY
 pel.end_date DESC;
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I changed "AND pel.start_date < pel.end_date" to "OR pel.start_date < pel.end_date"

Comment: I see from other comments that you're wanting "exclusive or" (or Xor), and have changed the code accordingly.